# Equivalent of python base32 encoding in bash

Tags: python-3.x, bash

What is the equivalent of b32encode in python in bash?

```
>>> from base64 import b64decode, b32encode
>>> b32encode(b"\327")
```

i tried
echo "\327" | base32 (but that yields a different result)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python, the expression `\ooo` is an octal literal (see "[String and byte literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)"), so the expression `\327` produces the value 215 (hex `D7`).

On the other hand, in the shell `echo "\327"` produces the literal value `\327`.

Since you're not encoding the same data in your two examples, you're getting different results.

The shell equivalent to your Python example would be:

```
echo -ne '\0327' | base32
```

Comment: python3 -c 'from base64 import b64decode, b32encode; print(b32encode(b"n\305"))'
b'N3CQ===='
echo -ne 'n\305' | base32
NZODGMBV
i do not think your answer is accurate

Comment: @david I am certain this answer is accurate. Please pay care attention to the syntax of the `echo` statement. If you get the syntax right you'll get the output you expect.

Comment: what is wrong with echo -ne "n\305" | base32?
Please help, i connot see it

Comment: Note the leading `0` in `echo -ne '\0327'` in my answer. That is required for an octal escape. See e.g., the [echo man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/echo.1p.html).

Comment: You can also use `echo $'\327'` in bash.